# Cannot access a specific set of domains and web pages, but can access all others

Tags: networking, mac

I am unable to access a specific set of domains, but can access other web pages and domains without a problem.

The domains I cannot access are all hosted at the same IP, namely http://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=68.64.155.162&t=1 I administer a few of these domains, so initially I thought it was a problem with my domain, but it seems to be something much more strange.

I am using MAC 10.10.3. Trying to access these pages directly results in a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on Chrome and similar messages on Safari and Firefox.

If I go through a VPN, I can access these web pages.

I I go through an http-proxy, I can access these web pages.

If I use a different computer, in the same home network so with the same external IP address, I can access these web pages.

I do not think it is a DNS problem since the website name resolves properly but I cannot get to any web pages.

I am stumped. Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Can you do traffic capture and analysis (fancy words for tcpdumps) before and after your gateway to the world? You have to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Please post a ping and traceroute to the domain(s) in question.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: The IP was blocked in the firewall and it has been unblocked.
The cause was because of a ModSecurity firewall block.

Ping was returning no response

Traceroute was returning 12 hops and then firewall.

Being able to access the site from another device must have been a fluke or cache issue.

Thanks for suggestions.